# Cordova/PhoneGap - Do apps require internet?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I need to develop a phone app that does NOT require internet access to run.

Sorry, I know this is a completely bone head question to ask but NONE of the frameworks I’m looking at seem to clearly state this. Do apps created with this framework require internet for them to work? I think the correct term is “are they native?” but I’m self taught and don’t always know my terminology.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use Cordova/PhoneGap to build an app that works without Internet access.

Apps built with Cordova/PhoneGap are `hybrid` apps. Think of Cordova/PhoneGap as a technology that gives you a container which lets you build an app using the `universal` web-based HTML, CSS JavaScript instead of having to code in platform specific APIs.

It's just like a browser but with access to device hardware such as camera, storage, location, etc...

And with services like `PhoneGap Build` (https://build.phonegap.com/), they will build the app for you, so you don't even need Xcode or Android SDK toolchains.

The app, the end result, that container... is in essence exposing some sort of a connector between the device (the smartphone, tablet, etc...) and your HTML, CSS and JavaScript.